# Matrix topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the space of all real $n \times n$ matrices. We define the function $f \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as the rank of a matrix. We induce the standard Euclidean topology on $X$. Show that for all $x$ in $X$ and for all $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x \in X; f(x) \leq a \}$ is closed in $X$.

My book says that I should prove that a small change in the components of each vector of a matrix doesn't change the rank of a matrix. I don't understand this because I thought that I have to prove that the boundary of the set is in the set. We view a matrix as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$. There has to exist a matrix such that for every open ball with center in the matrix there exists an element of the ball that has the same rank as the matrix and there exists an element of the ball which has a different rank. Intuitively this means that small changes both preserve and change the rank of a matrix which is in contradiction with the hint in my book. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that a small change can only increase the rank.  For example, let
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then changing $A_{2,2}$ by a little will change the rank, but only increase it.  To show that small changes can only increase the rank, note that a column of a matrix represents the vector to which that matrix maps the basis vector that corresponds to that column.

After you show the above fact, then take a convergent sequence of matrics $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ all with rank less than or equal to $n$.  Show that the limit point of this sequence has rank less than or equal to $n$.